# [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load(byte[]) failed: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, powershell

I got a Windows service written in C# that executes Powershell command. It tries to load Azure Storage dll and fails.

```
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($azureStorageDll) // local path of the dll
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes) | Out-Null
```

The dll is in package version 9.0.0. And the error is `Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Interestingly, if I run the Windows service under my credentials, it works. But it fails when running under the bot account. And 9.3.2 is not even the latest version

I tried printing out the GAC under the bot account but I don't see anything related to Azure Storage

```
$n1 = New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry' -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
$n2 = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCR:\Installer\Assemblies\Global' | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty
```

I understand there are various contexts when loading dlls. But I don't know how to debug this? Could someone please help with some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling Fusion logging, then signing in to windows as the bot user and attempting to load the DLL. Fusion logs will probably show that there is a dependent DLL that is not readable by your service account, probably due to filesystem permissions.

Here's a [Powershell script](https://github.com/mossrich/PowershellRecipes/blob/master/ToggleFusionLogging.ps1) that makes it easier to toggle the state of Fusion logging:

```
Param( $LogPath = "c:\temp\Fusion" )

#restart as admin if not started as admin 
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { 
    Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -PassThru -Verb RunAs | Out-null; exit 
}
$RegKey = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion'
If(!(Test-Path $RegKey)) {New-Item -Path $RegKey -ItemType Container | Out-Null}
$NewValue = If((Get-ItemProperty $RegKey).EnableLog -eq 1){0} Else {1}
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name EnableLog        -Value $NewValue -Type DWord
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name ForceLog         -Value $NewValue -Type DWord
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name LogFailures      -Value $NewValue -Type DWord
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name LogResourceBinds -Value $NewValue -Type DWord
Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name LogPath          -Value $LogPath  -Type String
If(!(Test-Path $LogPath -PathType Container)){New-Item $LogPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null}
Write-Host "$(If($NewValue -eq 1){'Enabled'}Else{'Disabled'}) Fusion Logging at $LogPath"
If(!$Host.Name.Contains("ISE")){Pause}
```

Comment: This tool is insane! Thanks. For those who are looking, Fusion logging is in Windows SDK which can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer. I think I was using `AutoGenerateBindingRedirects` and for some reason, it generate `9.3.2.0` version which my service account doesn't have access to

Comment: I hope you were able to resolve your issue. Remember to toggle Fusion logging off when you've figured out the cause. If you leave it enabled, the log folders get very full and your system performance will suffer.

Comment: I made an open source reimplementation of the fusion log viewer called [Fusion++](https://twitter.com/Waescher/status/1129520190126010369). It is designed for the year 2019 and @RichMoss, it automatically stops logging as soon as it gets closed ;)